# Questions about fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am learning fixed-point iteration and am confused about the convergence rate, which is defined as follows:

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}-x^*}{(x_k-x^*)^p}=C,\quad C\neq 0$$
Then we call the iteration process is $p$-order convergent.

My question is when the iteration process is $p+1$ order convergent, is it $p, p-1, \cdots, 1$ order convergent?

My thoughts, suppose we have

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}-x^*}{(x_k-x^*)^{p+1}}=C,\quad C\neq 0$$

then, $$\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}-x^*}{(x_k-x^*)^{p}}*\frac{1}{(x_k-x^*)}=C,\quad C\neq 0$$

If the first term converges to some constant, then contradicts coz the second term goes to infinity.

Comment: Use backslashes in MathJax! `\lim`

Comment: You should show your thoughts - do *you* believe it is $1,2,\cdots,p$ order convergent? If so, why?

Comment: Can you figure out a relation between the quotients $\frac{x_{k+1}-x^*}{(x_k-x^*)^p}$ and  $\frac{x_{k+1}-x^*}{(x_k-x^*)^q}$ for positive integer values of $p$ and $q$? That relation will tell you the answer. Remember that $C$ is a finite *non-zero* real number.

Comment: I added my thoughts, is that right? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that that you have $C\ne 0$ in the definition... Can you have $C\ne 0$ for both $p$ and $p+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sequence $(x_k)$ converges to $x^*$ and we have that, for some $p$,
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} \dfrac{|x_{k+1}-x^*|}{|x_k-x^*|^p} = C_p \ne 0
$$

then,

- for any $q < p$, we have that
  $$
  \lim_{k\to \infty} \dfrac{|x_{k+1}-x^*|}{|x_k-x^*|^q} = 0
  $$
- for any $q>p$, we have that
  $$
  \lim_{k\to \infty} \dfrac{|x_{k+1}-x^*|}{|x_k-x^*|^q} = \infty
  $$

So, you see that the order of convergence, if finite, is uniquely determined.